# counting if certain things match

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, countif

I have a set of data that looks like this:

```
Period    Address Name                  City            Carrier Move ID  
P1/2014   WAL-MART CANADA INC.          MISSISSAUGA     CMV0066539  
P1/2014   WAL-MART CANADA INC.          MISSISSAUGA     CMV0066539  
P1/2014   WAL-MART CANADA INC.          MISSISSAUGA     CMV0066539  
P1/2014   WAL-MART CANADA INC.          MISSISSAUGA     CMV0066539  
P1/2014   COLABOR LIMITED PARTNERSHIP   BOUCHER         CMV0066544  
P1/2014   DISTRIBUTION FARINEX          BOISBRIAND      CMV0066544  
P2/2014   METRO RICHELIEU 2000 INC.     ST-JEAN         CMV0066544  
P2/2014   METRO RICHELIEU 2000 INC.     ST-JEAN         CMV0066544  
P2/2014   METRO RICHELIEU 2000 INC.     MONTREAL        CMV0066544  
P2/2014   SYSCO QUEBEC (684)            MONTREAL        CMV0066544  
P2/2014   BAKEMARK INGREDIENTS CDA      LAVAL           CMV0066544  
P3/2014   DIST ALIMANTAIRE FRANK&DINO   MONTREAL        CMV0066544  
P3/2014   SOCIETE EN COMMANDITE         ST-JEAN         CMV0066551  
P3/2014   DUBORD & RAINVILLE INC        VILLE           CMV0066551   
P3/2014   LES VENTES RUDOLPH 2000 INC   MONTREAL        CMV0066551  
P3/2014   PRICE COSTCO DIST CENTRE      ST-BRUNO        CMV0066551  
P3/2014   WAL-MART CANADA INC.          CORNWALL        CMV0066575  
P3/2014   WAL-MART CANADA INC.          CORNWALL        CMV0066575  
P3/2014   WAL-MART CANADA INC.          CORNWALL        CMV0066575  
P3/2014   DOLLARAMA L.P.                MONTREAL        CMV0066575  
P3/2014   WAL-MART CANADA INC.          CORNWALL        CMV0066575   
P4/2014   WAL MART                      MISSISSAUGA     CMV0066577  
P4/2014   WAL-MART CANADA INC.          MISSISSAUGA     CMV0066577  
P4/2014   WAL-MART CANADA INC.          MISSISSAUGA     CMV0066577  
P4/2014   WAL-MART CANADA INC.          MISSISSAUGA     CMV0066577  
P4/2014   SHOPPER'S DRUG MART           CORNWALL        CMV0066632  
P4/2014   WAL-MART                      CORNWALL        CMV0066632  
P4/2014   COLABOR LIMITED PARTNERSHIP   BOUCHERVILLE    CMV0066632
```

I want to be able to count, per period, if there is multiple carrier move IDs going to the same address. so the first 3 are the perfect example, there are 3 of the same Carrier Move Ids going to the same address in the Same city.  I want to know how many times this occurs throughout my entire data, sperated by customer.

I would be happy with something as simple as this, where i'm looking for the formula that will give me the duplication number, I can create the remaining chart.:

```
Period  Customer                    Duplication?  
P1/2014 WAL-MART CANADA INC.            1  
P2/2014 METRO RICHELIEU 2000 INC.       1  
P3/2014 WAL-MART CANADA INC.            1
```

Comment: (1) Even after reading the exchange of comments on the answer, I don't understand this question. Can you please try harder to say what you want, clearly? (2) When people don't understand your question, it's better for you to [edit] the question rather than to respond in comments. (3) We don't need to see your _actual_ data; we need to see only enough to understand your question -- a representative sample. Your data example hurts my eyes; can you cut it down? ...

Comment: ... For example, do you need all the columns? It looks (in my, admittedly flawed, understanding) like the `Carrier` column isn't a factor. Then, shorten the words: `P1/WAL-MART`, `P1/COLABOR`, `P2/METRO`, ..., `373`, `392`, `524`, ..., `39`, `44`, `51`, ..., etc. Horizontal scrolling is terrible for readability. Also, please fix the example so the columns line up. Finally, reduce the number of rows. You should be able to give examples of what you want counted and what you don't want counted in half as many rows.

Comment: OK, I see you've edited the question; thanks for that. But (4) it still lacks a clear ***explanation*** of what you want. (5) Providing inconsistent data doesn't help. Your sample results show `P1/2014_` ... `WalMart` and `P2/2014_` ... `Costco` when there are no corresponding data in the input. And (6) please format your data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't totally clear but here's an idea: Add a unique ID that combines the Period, Address, City, and CarrierMoveID. I pasted your data into `A1` on a new worksheet and here's the formula I used to create a unique ID in column G:

```
=A2&"|"&B2&"|"&C2&"|"&F2
```

I like pipes to separate things. Tweak the UID to whatever you really need. Then, in the next column over, use a formula like this in the first record (row 2):

```
=IF(COUNTIF($G$1:$G1,$G2)>0,0,COUNTIF($G:$G,$G2))
```

That'll give you a count each time that UID shows up but only the *first* time it shows up. You could drop the whole thing into a pivot table to summarize by period and customer if you like. I ended up with this:
[image: PivotTable Results Screenshot]

Comment: not quite what I was hoping for.  there are thousands of carrier move IDs(CMV) because each shipment has its own ID.  I was hoping to just be able to count how many times the CMV repeats to the same customer.  

So if there is repeat in column F, I want something to look to see if there is also a repeat in column B of those repeated rows.

Comment: That's fine, then. I wasn't sure how you wanted to define "address" in your initial question. Just change the formula for unique ID. `=A2&"|"&B2&"|"&F2`.  Alternatively, if all you care about is a count in the data and not some summary, you can use the `COUNTIFS` function. `=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2,F:F,F2)`

Comment: that only works if I drag that formula down my entire data set, I was more hoping for a forumla that I could put on a dashboard.

Comment: Let's back and and look at it again, then. What do you want? What about a table where the rows are different customers, the columns are different period, and the values are how many times that customer in that period has a duplicate carrier ID? Could you mock up what result you're looking for and edit your post so I can see what your desired final result is?